# how to fix attribute error in a page summarizer

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning

getting a attribute error in my page summarizer model when trying to get a token but keep getting error and cant seem to see anything wrong with it.

```
def text():
      for i in range(0,len(text_p)):
        text += text_p[i].text
        text = text.lower()


# tokenize the text
tokens =[t for t in text.split()]
print(tokens)
```

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
      6 
      7 # tokenize the text
----> 8 tokens =[t for t in text.split()]
      9 print(tokens)

AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'split'

Answer (score 0):

> you are using the function name and variable name as "text"

change your varibale name or the function name

Comment: your variable declaration is not clear... mind explaining what this code is for and what each variables do